# SIGABRTと表示される

Tags: swift

https://akira-watson.com/iphone/tableview_3.html

上記のサイトにあるコードを写経しているのですが、実行すると

```
let subVC: SubViewController = (segue.destinationViewController as? SubViewController)!
```

の部分が SIGABRTと表示されます。

SIGABRTとはコードを入力する順番が違う、某サイトで見たのですが、今回もそういうことなのでしょうか。。。

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController , UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{

    @IBOutlet var table:UITableView!

    let imgArray: NSArray = ["img0.png", "img1.png", "img2.png", "img3.png"]

    let label2Array: NSArray = ["あ", "い", "え", "う"]

    var selectedImage: UIImage?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return imgArray.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = table.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("tableCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

        let img = UIImage(named: "\(imgArray[indexPath.row])")

        let imageView = table.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView
        imageView.image = img

        let label1 = table.viewWithTag(2) as! UILabel
        label1.text = "No.\(indexPath.row + 1)"

        let label2 = table.viewWithTag(3) as! UILabel
        label2.text = "\(label2Array[indexPath.row])"

        return cell

            }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        selectedImage = UIImage(named:"\(imgArray[indexPath.row])")
        if selectedImage != nil {

        performSegueWithIdentifier("toSubViewController", sender: nil)
    }

    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
        if (segue.identifier == "toSubViewController") {
            let subVC: SubViewController = (segue.destinationViewController as? SubViewController)!
            subVC.selectedImg = selectedImage

        }
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

「SIGABRT」は、多種の原因で出るエラーメッセージで、とくに「コードを入力する順番が違う」ことに特定できるものではありません。

プログラムコードの「写経」は、コードの一行一行、ひとつの語句それぞれがどういう意味を持っているのか、意識しながら行わないと、意味のない行為に陥ります。

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = table.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("tableCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) // table→tableView

    let img = UIImage(named: "\(imgArray[indexPath.row])")

    let imageView = table.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView
    imageView.image = img // table→tableView

    let label1 = table.viewWithTag(2) as! UILabel // table→tableView
    label1.text = "No.\(indexPath.row + 1)"

    let label2 = table.viewWithTag(3) as! UILabel // table→tableView
    label2.text = "\(label2Array[indexPath.row])"

    return cell

        }
```

ここがいい例ですが、メソッドの引数`tableView`と、メソッドの実装内で使われている変数`table`が一致していないことに気づかず「写経」していては、仏様はけっして降臨してきません。

エラーの原因の箇所だけでなく、全体を見直して書き直してみました。

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController , UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{

    // Storyboardで定義したオブジェクトには、weak属性を付ける。
    @IBOutlet weak var table:UITableView!

    // NSArray型にキャストする意味はありません。逆にSwiftの配列のままであれば、要素をいちいちダウンキャスト（as? String）しなくてすむ。
    let imgArray: [String] = ["img0.png", "img1.png", "img2.png", "img3.png"]
    // 同様に、NSArrayにキャストしない。
    let label2Array: [String] = ["あ", "い", "え", "う"]

    var selectedImage: UIImage?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return imgArray.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("tableCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

        // NSArrayのキャストをやめたおかげで、すっきりシンプルなコードになりました。
        let img = UIImage(named: imgArray[indexPath.row])

        let imageView = tableView.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView
        imageView.image = img

        let label1 = table.viewWithTag(2) as! UILabel
        label1.text = "No.\(indexPath.row + 1)"

        let label2 = table.viewWithTag(3) as! UILabel
        // これもすっきりシンプル。
        label2.text = label2Array[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        // これもすっきりシンプルで。
        // Optional Binding構文を使う。
        if let image = UIImage(named: imgArray[indexPath.row]) {
            selectedImage = image 
            performSegueWithIdentifier("toSubViewController", sender: nil)
        }
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
        if (segue.identifier == "toSubViewController") {
            // Optional Binding構文を使う。
            if let subVC = segue.destinationViewController as? SubViewController {
                subVC.selectedImg = selectedImage
            }
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

}
```

これでまだエラーが出るようでしたら、コメント欄にコメントください。

Comment: SIGABRT が POSIX の `signal`(3) の `SIGABRT` のことであるならば、「Signal aborted」の略ではありませんし、「信号が中断された」という意味でもありません。

Comment: @fumiyas すみません。該当箇所を削除しました。

Comment: @fumiyas でしたら、「中断という信号」という意味になるんでしょうか？

Comment: はい、そうです。何らかの理由で `abort`(3) が呼ばれ、`SIGARRT` (abort signal) が送られたのでしょう。
https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B7%E3%82%B0%E3%83%8A%E3%83%AB_%28%E3%82%BD%E3%83%95%E3%83%88%E3%82%A6%E3%82%A7%E3%82%A2%29

Comment: できました！写経、意味を調べてながらやっていこうと思います。正直書き直してくださったコードもちんぷんかんぷんなので。。。それは自力で勉強します。ありがとうございました！

Comment: @fumiyas ありがとうございました。iOSもまた、ベースはUNIXということだったんですね。

Answer (score 1):

質問に書いてある参考にしているサイトの『1. 画面遷移先の View Controller を新しく作成』の部分に以下のような記述がありますが、この部分はちゃんと設定されているでしょうか？

> ストーリーボードで 新しく作った View Controller を選択して
>   ライブラリーエリアの Identity Inspector に入り
>   「Custom Class」の「Class」から、候補が選択できます
>
> SubViewController を選択

実行時のSIGABRTは、segue.destinationViewControllerをSubViewControllerにキャストしようとして失敗したのが原因のように思われます。

Comment: いけました！！ありがとうございます。サイトには記述されていなかったので当たり前のことだったのですかね。助かりました。三連休はswiftの勉強がはかどりそうです。

Answer (score 0):

Table View Cell の　Attributes inspector で　Identifier に　「tableCell」と指定出来ていますか？